# Pattern matching across rows/columns of dataframe (conceptual question)

Tags: r

I'm building a parser for complex and large CSV files. The file is quite irregular with many blocks of information spread around the document. I have two conceptual questions:

- How could I approach 'finding' these blocks of data to extract and
  parse them individually? [image: (image 1)]
- Same as 1) but now the blocks
  are not 'complete' rectangles? Essentially the task here is to carve
  out any contiguously filled blocks of data. [image: (image 2)]

Comment: I thought I had an idea for the first half - but it wouldn't work for the second half. Some times in data science, The most important job is making sure our colleagues give us data in a neat format. (or at least some type of consistency).

Comment: Thanks Justin. I'd be grateful for a solution to the first problem. Or again, at least a conceptual idea. I'm thinking of maybe turning the df into a matrix that is filled with 1/0 based on na vs. !na. There has to be some good way of doing some matrix calculations to find rectangles across these matrices (at least within a certain size boundary for x/y -- e.g. search for rows that contain stretches of 1 larger than 5. Then once the first one is found you can extend it to the row below and see how far it goes. Once you fill a rectangle you can then turn everything to 0 and look for the next.

Comment: Actually, something similar might work for the other problem. Find the first 1. Look at all 8 neighbors and grow it out from there iteratively. Once you reach 0 for all new neighbors you see if the overall size fulfils a minimum size. If it does you set all vals to 0 and either parse or don't parse.

Actually, probably even faster if you look for the first 1 that is surrounded on all sides with 1s and grow out until you identify the boundary of the object. That would actually be a universal solution to the problem. :D